# Displaying elements of a class in a row instead of vertically - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, array-map

So I am trying to display elements of a class in a row in HTML. I am unsure how to do this as my .js file will just print them vertically and not horizontally.

This is my files at the moment:

recipeCard.js

```
class recipeCard {
  constructor(name, desc, time, numPeople, image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.time = time;
    this.numPeople = numPeople;
    this.image = image;
  }
}

export default recipeCard;
```

data.js

```
import recipeCard from "./recipeCard.js";

const eggBites = new recipeCard(
  "Bacon Cheddar Egg Bites",
  "Delicious, easy breakfast treat!",
  "15-20 Minutes",
  "1 Person",
  "/eggbites.png"
);

console.log(eggBites);

const buffaloSliders = new recipeCard(
  "Buffalo Chicken Sliders",
  "Easy lunch/any time of day dish!",
  "25 Minutes",
  "1-3 People",
  "../buffalosliders.png"
);

console.log(buffaloSliders);

const recipeCardArray = [eggBites, buffaloSliders];

console.log("Array: ", recipeCardArray);

export default recipeCardArray;
```

script.js
(The div class="row" was my CSS attempt to display it in a row but then realized that each element of the class will be in its own row with this code)

```
import recipeCardArray from "./components/data.js";

console.log("Array in script file: ", recipeCardArray);

const recipeCardList = recipeCardArray.map((recipeCard) => {
  let recipeCardArticle = document.createElement("article");
  recipeCardArticle.classList.add("recipeCard");
  recipeCardArticle.setAttribute("name", recipeCard.name);

  recipeCardArticle.innerHTML = `
  <center><div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="icon">
            <img src=${recipeCard.image} alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="food">
                ${recipeCard.name}
            </h1>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">${recipeCard.time}</i>
            <i class="fa fa-users">${recipeCard.numPeople}</i>

            <div class="stars">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <p class="info">${recipeCard.desc}</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Recipe Here</a>
    </div>
    </div></center>
`;

  return recipeCardArticle;
});

//Appends each recipeCard item to the main
const main = document.querySelector(".maincontent");

recipeCardList.forEach((recipeCard) => {
  main.append(recipeCard);
});
```

I tried doing CSS to display the elements horizontally, but I realized that even with the CSS class in there to make horizontal rows, each element will print with its own individual row. I want to keep the innerHTML calling the respective properties of each element instead of coding each element one by one to display them. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that defines the CSS classes you are consuming (e.g. `row`)?  W/ out that information, it's hard to tell what the root cause is.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) like this:

main.css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

In here, we are creating a class called `row`, and then using flexbox and the direction to be row. Check out the link I provided to see more about flexbox.